# How to split the text retrieved from `div` elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have this HTML:

```
<div class="chip">java<span class="material-icons close">×</span></div>
<div class="chip">spring<span class="material-icons close">×</span></div>
<div class="chip">python<span class="material-icons close">×</span></div>
```

With the following script I try to retrieve the texts without the `x`. I get the values of the `div` elements using their class name, but when passed to split it, the same string returns without any split:

```
var skills = $('.chip').text();
var arr = skills.split('x');
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    alert(arr[i]);
}
```

For example:

```
var skills = 'javaxspringxpython';
```

The output remains the same. I know this is because of the `.text()` method, but not sure how to solve this. I tried using `.val()`, but that didn't work.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Please show us the markup where you get the _skills_ from.

Comment: *"I know this is because of the .text() method"*: you cannot know this with the `text` method, or did you assume that the call to `split` would update your HTML content?

Comment: I mean the problem might be because of .text() method and i am not assuming anything regarding any updation to HTML.

Comment: please add relevant html

Comment: Hope this is enough.

Comment: @PrasannaKumarSR you're using a character different from an `x` in your html, maybe because you did a copy paste from somewhere. try deleting and writing the `x` again in your html

Comment: I have not copy pasted, but I have used &times; instead of directly using 'x'. Would that pose a problem?

Comment: You have 2 `.chip` in markup so when using jQuery selector, it returns an array of 2 items. You are doing a split on this array but you intend to do so on its contents.

Comment: @OmarIlias You are partially right. Because I was using &times; instead of 'x', the .text() was unable to split it. Now I replaced with 'x' and it is working fine. Thank you all.

Comment: @PrasannaKumarSR `var arr = skills.split(copy_paste_the_x_from_your_html_here);`

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML has already three separate elements.

Instead of splitting the combined text, you could get the individual contents of the tags, and kick out any other tags from that content (the `span` elements in your case). Then you will have three matching text nodes, which you then need to map to array items:

```js
var skills = $('.chip').contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3; // only immediate text in div, not in span
}).map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
}).get();

console.log(skills);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="chip">java<span class="material-icons close">×</span></div>
<div class="chip">spring<span class="material-icons close">×</span></div>
<div class="chip">python<span class="material-icons close">×</span></div>
```

Comment: That's not strictly true. `.text()` in jQuery gets the combined text contents of each element in the set of matched elements  - http://api.jquery.com/text/

Comment: Thanks for highlighting that. I removed it from my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Its Work For Me..

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var skills = $('.chip').text();
    var arr = skills.split('x');
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        // alert(arr[i]);
        console.log(arr[i]);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='chip'>javaxspringxpython</div>
```

Hope Its Work !!!

Happy Coding !!